# What is the best way to implement fulltext search for Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, lucene, solr

What is the best way to implement fulltext search for Google App Engine Java?

- Solr doesn't work out of the box
- Lucene-based searchengine has limitation with the index size
- the latest search is not available for Java yet (experimental or not)

So what you using for fulltext search for GAE Java now?

Comment: Related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414817/full-text-search-on-google-app-engine-java

Answer (score 3):

You could always use an [external, hosted search server solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168634/hosted-full-text-search-solutions). Be sure to measure latency and throughput from GAE servers though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you [integrate google search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) itself in your app.

Comment: Control. We need more control over the search and besides this is not a website but a webapp. :-)